# How To Redirect /url.html to /url?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I want to rediret

```
mysite.com/page-url.html/
```

to

```
mysite.com/page-url/
```

How can i do that ?

I tried to create page rule in cloudflare like this

```
- mysite.com/*.html
```

to

```
mysite.com/*
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in Your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

alternatively You could use in your php code:

```
 wp_redirect(str_replace('.html', '', $url))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. actully i used search & replace plugin and updated .html to /